# =SUMIF() Google Spreadsheets Date Range

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, sumifs

**OBJECTIVE**

To have Google Spreadsheets sum a column (investments) if the dates match correctly

**PROBLEM**

Google Spreadsheet's "sumif" statement only enables me to sum dates *prior* (or after) a Given Date - I cannot sum the Investments column that fall within a given month (between dates; e.g 10/1/2015 - 10/30/2015).

**EXAMPLE**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PSxVCOnn3JZGvfFu8v6QHTFxcQwmAQkdENMTG7ywu-o/edit?usp=sharing

**QUESTION(S)**

1. How can I create a system that looks up a range of dates and returns the amount of dollars invested for that given month? I've tried sumif() and vlookup() to no avail.

Comment: Add a helper column which gives you the value if if complies with your condition, sum that helper column.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved my own problem, however the equation can be slightly improved.

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A6,B2:B6,">="&B9,B2:B6,"<="&B9+30)
```

^^^ Sum the Investment Columns (A2:A6); if the Date Columns (B2:B6) fall between the Given Date (B9) and the end of that month (B9+30), then summarize the columns for the Given Range.

It's a bit of a hack, especially the B9+30, but it works for now..